# How to add subscribers to multiple different publication lists using automation

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, salesforcedx, automationstudio

I am trying to add all the subscribers coming from a cloud page to 5 different publication lists.
The subscribers data is being recorded in a data extension and want to use it to add to the 5 publication lists automatically.
How can I achieve this in Marketing cloud using any of the automation.

Comment: You need to first export the data extension into a comma-delimited file and save it to the FTP, then transfer it from FTP Safehouse to the Import folder on FTP, and then use the Import activity to import it to each of your publication lists. So set up the automation in that order: Export > Transfer > Import x5. You could also look into doing it via WSProxy if you want to do it programatically.

Comment: So the Import file for publication list needs subscriber key which is not a column available in data extension, any solution for that?

Comment: It would be best to modify the cloud page so that it adds all necessary information into your DE

Comment: So the cloud page does take in email and names but in the DE itself there isnt a column for subscriber key, Is there  a way to populate it with query?

Comment: No need to use a query, just add a subscriber key column to the DE and populate it from the Cloud Page

Comment: So If I understand this correctly you want this to be a field in cloud page and data extension, and user would enter this ? So I dont think the subscriber key can be entered by the user unless if the email itself is the subscriber key which its not.